# module 'torch' has no attribute 'linalg'

Tags: pytorch, attributeerror

I am getting this error `AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'linalg'` when updating the parameters using `optimizer.step(model.closure)`.
I am using Pytorch version 1.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linalg` was introduced to pytorch only on a later version (1.7.0). Update pytorch and try again.

Comment: I tried conda update --all. It doesn't update pytorch.

Comment: @PrakharSharma current version is 1.10.0 -- please follow the installation instructions [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) to get it.